# Cron expression to human readable expression in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cron, quartz-scheduler

Can someone suggest a utility in angularjs that can covert a quartz cron expression to human readable string?

I have tried

1. [Angular Corn Humanize](https://github.com/StrongeLeeroy/angular-cron-humanize)
2. Pretty Cron for Javascript
3. Later.js

None seems to work. Not sure if I am missing something. Please help!
Angular version - 1.5.8

Answer (score 3):

Actually you yourself answered this question.
PrettyCron works like a charm.

```
prettyCron.toString("0 0/10 * ? * * ", true)
```

"Every 10 minutes"